# How risky are boolean modifiers?

Tags: modifiers

Years ago, I did some 3D work in Truespace. In Truespace, using boolean operations was a sure way the seriously mess up you mesh; many times to the point where you basically needed to restart from scratch.

I searched this site a bit and there seem to be a lot of problems related to *Boolean modifiers*.

So, **my questions are**:

- How risky are Boolean Modifiers?
- What 'rules' should I stick to, to minimize the risks?
- Can I safely `apply` them?

---

I played around a bit with the scenario below, where I tried cutting a doorway into a wall with a Boolean Modifier (difference).

[image]

And it seems to work without unexpected side effects.

However, at least in Truespace, 'seeing no evil' is no guarantee that the mesh is still Ok. Hence my question.

Comment: AFAIK there aren't really any side effects other than mesh problems. If the resulting mesh has the correct topology and normals, there isn't really anything else that would be messed up as a side effect. That is, I have never known boolean modifiers to crash Blender, relink material nodes, delete animations, etc. In other words, "seeing no evil" is almost always the same as having no problems, because boolean modifier problems are (almost?) exclusively visual.

Comment: To stay absolutely safe, make sure to keep copies of pre-modified meshes separate. Depending on your desired result, you might find yourself frankensteining faces from pre-modified and modified meshes.

Comment: In my experience they are safe. Whenever I had problems with booleans, it turned out to be my fault, not Blender's. Note that a faster "boolean workflow" is possible with the Bool Tool and Carver addons, both of them are bundled with Blender since version 2.78.

Comment: I really appreciate all the answers! however, I can't accept comments. So, feel free to expand your comments into an answer :-)

Comment: I would pretty much never, under any circumstances, use a boolean.  They spit out bad topology and are the cause of untold headaches. To me they are lazy in a really bad way. And I admire laziness.